# mongoimport and header line contains in 2nd line

Tags: mongodb, csv

I am importing a CSV file into MongoDB. I have a `region.csv` file which contains the first line as header line.

I used the following command:

```
 mongoimport -h localhost --db maxmind  --collection region --type csv --file region.csv --headerline
```

It worked fine. Now I have another CSV file which contains the first line as some copyright line and 2nd line as header line. I can delete the first line and used the same command. But without deleting the first line manually, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using an environment with the standard Linux/Unix [`tail` utility](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/tail.1.html), you can use `tail -n` to start from a specified number of lines from the beginning or end of a text file.

In your case, you want to start from the second line of the CSV file (so `tail -n +2`) and would need to pipe the output of tail to `mongoimport`.

Putting that together, the command line would look like:

```
 tail -n +2 another.csv | mongoimport --db maxmind --collection region --type csv --headerline
```

Note that you also don't need to specify `-h localhost` as this is the default value.